# C++ container with expiration time

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I want to create a C++(11) container (boost can be used) that will hold database connections. I would like to be able to push in the container the connection pointer, however std::vector does not know the insertion time so I can used something like this.

- When the connection starts execution it will also pushed in the
  container with the time now().

  If the connection finishes the job in the db the connection will be
  erased from the container.

Ideally my class will have a cleanup method that will check periodically if a connection is in the container for more than a specific time interval, ie 30 sec. If it is true the connection will be released from the database.

Any ideas, is there any standard solution?

Comment: Have you checked if your database driver supports connection pooling? Might be worth a look before you reinvent half of that wheel.

Comment: It does support, however some queries can take too much time keeping the database row locked, and we don't want this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a vector of pairs. Where each pair's first element would be the insertion time and the second element would be the connection pointer.

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, ConnectionPtr*>> connections_vec;
```

Additionally, you could make use of STL `std::partition` in order to get rid of expired connections as:

```
connections_vec.erase(std::partition(connections_vec.begin(), 
                                     connections.vec.end(),
                                     [](auto &&p){return (time_now - p.first) > 30secs;}), 
                                     connections_vec.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various possible solutions to your needs.

You may still use std::vector<> but containing a struct defined by you that contains both the DB connection instance and a time, i.e. (roughly jotted code):

```
struct TimedConnection {
  DBConnection& connection;
  time_t connected_time;
};
std::vector<TimedConnection> myConnections;
```

Or, alternatively, use an `std::pair<DBConnection, time_t>` as vector item.

Note that the custom struct option will allow you greater freedom for future evolution or improvements, because it's not limited to 2 data as `std::pair<>`.

If the only use of such a container is to periodically check if there are DB connections started more than X seconds ago, you may also look at [std::priority_queue<>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), possibly with a custom comparison operator on the item struct (or pair).